# Questions that are not in English (or broken English)

Tags: discussion

I saw [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/77960/how-can-i-convert-a-4-color-object-to-single-color-in-indesign), which was originally written in Arabic.

The author clarified what they were asking, so I edited the title. In the
process, I edited the question, based on what I thought they were asking
(and using Google translate). It seemed like a simple question and I wanted to help "save" it. I also put a possible duplicate in the comments.

My question is:

1.) Should I have attempted to save this question or flagged it for deletion?

2.) While this is clearly an English language site, is there an explicit
rule that says questions must be in English? I actually couldn't find one
in the Help Center.

3.) Is it OK to aggressively edit the question of a non-English speaker to help better
get their point across?

I sometimes see questions that are clearly written by a non-native speaker
that have down votes for language and clarity issues. I feel that is unfair
and makes the valuable resource that is this site less usable to
non-English speaking designers.

Comment: Congrats on the 2k!

Comment: ".. down votes for language and clari[t]y[?] issues ..": a downvote is to indicate that a question is not useful, so indeed this should not happen. Comments, and optionally flagging, are to do so. If a question *is* clear but badly written, everyone is allowed to make it a better one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/

[Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange)

Those two should answer your question. Basically, English is the language. Salvage if you feel you can but if not, closing is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Excellent! I guess it should have occurred to me that this would be a cross-site policy. In the future, I guess I should also refer the user to a site in their native language (does a list of such sites already exist?)